# Reading from login.xls file and append results in same file?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, xls

```
 Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\Tsss-Pc1\\Desktop\\login.xls"));

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        String uname = sheet.getCell(0, 0).getContents();
        d.findElement(By.id("inputEmail")).sendKeys(uname);
        String pwd = sheet.getCell(1, 0).getContents();
        d.findElement(By.id("inputPassword")).sendKeys(pwd);
        d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div/button")).click();
```

This is my code for reading user name and password from login.xls, i want to append the results in the third column in same file.

```
   WritableCell label = new Label(2,0, "pass");
        WritableSheet sheet1 = null;
        sheet1.addCell(label);
```

I tryed with this code, but it's not working for me..
can any one tell me, how to do this...

Comment: Do you not need to instantiate the sheet1 object? From the code above, it seems to be still `null` when you try and call the addCell method.

Comment: Yes i am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: So what i have to do it...

Answer (score 0):

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("d://output6.xls"));
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);

            Label label = new Label(0, 0, "pass"); 
             sheet.addCell(label);                  
                 workbook.write(); 
                    workbook.close();

                 }
```

Comment: give some explanations also